# How come no one outside my network can connect to my Owncloud server?

Tags: installation, networking, webserver

I installed lawn software for internet online for my server, I installed owncloud 4 on it.
I can connect to it using my newwork internet, but no one out side my internet newwork can connect, they say it says can not connect to server. How to I fix this?
the ip to the server is: 192.168.0.102

Comment: what should the UDP and TCP ports be set to??? please help

Comment: I set them to 80 and its not going, its just saying can not connect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are giving your internal IP address, which means that users would have to be in your LAN to use it. If you want to allow outside access you'll have to port-forward the proper port (Most likely 80) to your machine. This can be done in the settings for your router.

Comment: what do I do if I don't know the password?

Comment: You have to know the password, otherwise you need to ask someone who does (Did another family member set it up), or see if there is a reset function on your router.