# Remote Access to Owncloud Server

Tags: networking, server, cloud

I'm currently trying to setup my own own-cloud server, and I've got it fully installed, configured, and accessible *from within my own local network*. I cannot figure out how to access it from the outside. So far I've:

- Successfully setup port-forwarding on my local router.

  - I've done so via 'single port forwarding' and 'port range forwarding'
  - Ports 80, 443, 3306 (Apache-Full and MySQL)
- Successfully obtained my external IP address.

  - I've also tested this magic number from within the network at `#insertIPhere/owncloud` and it did work.
- Successfully setup the server using SQLite
- Successfully setup the server using MySQL
- Created the following exceptions in my firewall:

  - Allow In Port 80   (Apache Full)
  - Allow In Port 443  (Apache Full)
  - Allow In Port 3306 (MySQL)
- Tried connecting from several different remote networks, as to troubleshoot something on their end

As far as trying to access it, I'm doing so through `Google-Chrome` and `Mozilla Firefox` trying to reach the server through `#insertIPhere/owncloud` using the above public IP address.

So what have I missed, and how do I access my server from outside?

Thanks in advance for your help and time, and I apologize in advance for what will probably result in my noobish mistake in networking.

I've looked at the [official documentation](http://doc.owncloud.org/server/4.5/admin_manual/installation.html). And also this question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159205/how-come-no-one-outside-my-network-can-connect-to-my-owncloud-server).

Comment: Odd. It should work. What router do you have? Also, did you try forwarding 443?

Comment: I've got the Cisco/Linksys E2500

Comment: No I haven't tried forwarding port 443, I'll try that in the morning.

Comment: Ok!  Good Luck !

Comment: I have it setup, but I have to get outside my network to test it...

Comment: It's saying "Suggestions: Try Reloading <#IPhere>/owncloud" whenever I try it on google chrome.

Comment: I don't need to edit any sort of apache configuration files do I?

Comment: Not unless you changed somethign

Comment: @John on router try DMZ to local machine ... Internet IP > Router ( DMZ ) > Local machine  ....

Comment: Not related to your question, but still: forwarding your MySQL port (i.e. giving access to your MySQL port outside your LAN) is a security threat.

Comment: Does your ISP block any ports? Mine (Cox) blocks 25, 80, 135, 136-139, 445, 1433, and 1900.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I need to look into that.. (I have cox too)

Comment: It appears that port 80 is definitely blocked, so I'm looking into how to change it.

Comment: @John if port 80 is blocked, you can try 8080 instead.  Change it from the apache configuration and forward it on your router, and if it's not blocked, you should be able to access it via http://your.ip:8080/owncloud.  Here's the change you need to make to your apache configuration: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/bind.html

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like everything is setup correctly and it should indeed work. Please check with your ISP if port 80 (http) is blocked.

Alternatively you can configure apache to use a different port (e.g. 1234) and then use the URL http://your.ip.he.re:1234/owncloud to try to reach the server.

If that's successful than your ISP is blocking port 80 (and potentially other ports too) and you'll need to use a port different from the blocked ones.

Answer (score 0):

We have created an app to automate router port mapping for owncloud: 
http://apps.owncloud.com/content/show.php/UPnp+Port+Mapper?content=162449

Answer (score -1):

This is exactly the sort of usage scenario tools like [PageKite](http://pagekite.net/) were created for.  I agree with Vitalie, it would be quite insecure to consider exposing your internal ports for this.

Comment: While the general idea to use such a service might be good, linking one such a service is a bit too much advertisement. Also you could include a description what such a service does and why it helps in this case.